# Multi Language insertion in SQL Server using a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, tamil

I need to insert Tamil language into SQL Server 2005. I have tried using `Insert` or `Update` query, it worked fine. While going to stored procedure, I don't know how to pass the parameter.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spr_Sam]
   @Row_Id       int            = NULL,
   @Description_Ta   nvarchar(MAX)  = null
AS
BEGIN
   update tblTest set  
   Description_Ta   = @Description_Ta
   where Row_Id = @Row_Id
END

exec [dbo].[spr_Sam] 2, 'பெண்டிரேம்';
```

If I execute this it gets inserted as ?????.

```
exec [dbo].[spr_Sam] 2, N'பெண்டிரேம்';
```

If I execute this it gets inserted correctly.. but I don't know how to pass that 'N' from my C# Application. I used a text-box to get that `Description_Ta` parameter.

Comment: Don't quote the parameter; `Description_Ta  = @Description_Ta`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct update statement:

```
update tblTest
    set  Description_Ta  = @Description_Ta
where Row_Id = @Row_Id;
```

You don't need single quotes around a variable.

But, I think the posting is confused.  To call the procedure use:

```
exec [dbo].[spr_Sam] 2, N'பெண்டிரேம்';
```

To modify it:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spr_Sam]     
    @Row_Id      int            = NULL,
    @Description_Ta  nvarchar(MAX)  = null
AS
BEGIN
    update tblTest
        set Description_Ta  = @Description_Ta
        where Row_Id = @Row_Id;
END;
```

You shouldn't have arguments when you define the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

C# should add the `N` automatically if you use `SqlDbType.NVarChar` for SQLParameter

You must be using `SqlDbType.VarChar` of course

The [MSDN doc for `SqlDbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx) states (my bold)

> VarChar: A variable-length stream of **non-Unicode** characters...
>
> ...
>
> NVarChar: A variable-length stream of **Unicode** characters...